# Find the maximum of $|\cos(z)|$ on a circle

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have to find the maximum of $|\cos(z)|$ on a circle given bij $|z| = \pi k$ ($k \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0})$. I found that you could use the Taylor series expansion of $\cos(z)$ to find the following:

$$|\cos(x)| \leq 1 - \frac{|x^2|}{2!} + \frac{|x^4|}{4!} - \dots$$

This is maximal for $x = i$ if we only look at the unit circle. But how can I expand this to a "random" circle given by $|z| = \pi k$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct estimate is
$$
|\cos(z)| = \left| 1 - \frac{z^2}{2!} + \frac{z^4}{4!}+ \ldots\right| 
\le 1 + \frac{|z|^2}{2!} + \frac{|z|^4}{4!} + \ldots = \cosh(|z|) \, .
$$
Equality holds for $z = \pm iy$, $y \in \Bbb R$. It follows that for any radius $r \ge 0$
$$
 \max_{|z|=r} |\cos(z)|  = \cosh(r) \, .
$$